# jQuery linking button with div

Tags: jquery, css, html, button

Okay So i'm trying to link a div with a button, there are multiple divs and each div will be assigned its own button, and what I'm trying to achieve is when ever a div is visible change the color of its button.

Here is my code so far, which doesn't work.

```
<ul style="padding-left:10em;">
    <li id="btID-1">1</li>
    <li id="btID-2">2</li>
    <li id="btID-3">3</li>
    <li id="btID-4">4</li>
</ul>
<div id="pgID-1" class="ui-content">content 1</div>
<div id="pgID-2" class="ui-content">content 2</div>
<div id="pgID-3" class="ui-content">content 3</div>
<div id="pgID-4" class="ui-content">content 4</div>
```

jquery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.ui-content').hide();
     $('#pgID-1').show();
     $(setPage);


     function setPage() {

         var active = $('.ui-content:visible');
         currPage = $('.ui-content:visible').index(active);


         currButton = $('.ui-dot').index(currPage);
         $(currButton).css("color:#ff0000");

     }

 });
```

I also want the buttons to show its div and hide the rest. I want to know what is wrong with my code and also if there is a better way of achieving the same thing.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Please show your HTML

Comment: how is the dom created?: is the div next to the button or is the button in the div? It makes a big difference to the complexity of the solution.

Comment: yeah next to the div not in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure I understand the requirements, but this should do the trick:

```
<ul id="btns" style="padding-left:10em;">
    <li id="btID-1">1</li>
    <li id="btID-2">2</li>
    <li id="btID-3">3</li>
    <li id="btID-4">4</li>
</ul>
<div id="pgID-1" class="ui-content">content 1</div>
<div id="pgID-2" class="ui-content">content 2</div>
<div id="pgID-3" class="ui-content">content 3</div>
<div id="pgID-4" class="ui-content">content 4</div>

 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.ui-content').hide();
     $('#pgID-1').show();

     $('#btns li').click(function(){
         $('.ui-content').hide();
         $('#btns li').css("color","black");
         var IDno = $(this).attr("id").substr(5);
         $('#pgID-'+IDno).show();
         $(this).css("color","red");
     });

 });
```

See the JSFiddle to see it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/w5QJK/12/

Comment: Okay but what If there were external buttons which also show / hide the divs, how would I set the color of these buttons.

Comment: External buttons? Where are these external buttons? Can you extend the JSFiddle to show what you mean?

Comment: Im not really at home at the moment to really to copy the file, but what I mean is that, I have a next / back button which cycles through the pages. That is why I figured maybe I could just use what div is visible to trigger the new buttons ive created, I wanted to simulate a dot navigation.

Comment: Hmmm, difficult to know your exact issue without seeing the code, but is this closer? http://jsfiddle.net/w5QJK/17/

Comment: No not quiet what I'm after, but I think this should help me figure it out, appreciate the help.

Comment: Shame. Glad it helped though. Best of luck.